# logout redirect url for microsoft identity provider and .net core (5) MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, .net-core, microsoft-identity-platform

Ive implemented a login/logout mechanism for my mvc azure app (.net core 5),  The login & logout methods work as expected but with one problem that I cant solve.  When a user logs out I want them to be redirected to a specific page within my app, not the default SignedOut.cshtml page the middleware provides.  There just doesnt seem to be a straightforward way to do this from within the .net core code of my app (that I can find).  Ive tried a few suggestions found after googling the issue, but nothing seems to work. This is how Ive Implemented MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication in the ConfigureServices method of startup.cs

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration);

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

whenever I logout Im always taken to the default signed out page supplied by Microsoft (SignedOut.cshtml), surely there must be an easy way to override this behaviour after the logout process has completed and redirect to a page of my choice, within my app.  I have this in the appsettings.json file within my app

```
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
"SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc"
```

Has anyone managed to do this ?  I'd really appreciate some advice

Comment: did you try: `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LogoutPath = $"/account/logout";
});`

Comment: I did but its exactly the same.  I assume Ill need to create my own account controller using this method ? (not use the default one in .net core)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by rewriting the URL. Try the below

```
app.UseRewriter(
 new RewriteOptions().Add(context =>
 {
     if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path == "/AzureAD/Account/SignedOut")
     { 
        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/SignedOut"); 
     }
   }));
```

Referenced: http://5.9.10.113/68376160/how-do-i-redirect-to-my-own-custom-logout-page-after-the-logout-process-has-comp